# Динамический массив внутри класса.

Tags: ооп, pascal

Здравствуйте уважаемые, пытаюсь использовать динамический массив внутри класса. Но ничего не выходит. Подскажите, в чём ошибка?

Основной файл:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas';

var test: TMyClass;
begin
  {TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }

   test.Add(43);
   Readln;

end.
```

Unit1

```
unit Unit1;

interface

type 
    TMyClass = class(TObject)
    public
    myArray: array of Integer;

  procedure Add( n: integer );
    end;

implementation

    procedure TMyClass.Add;
        begin
       SetLength( myArray, 1 );

           Writeln( 'Okay' );
        end;
end.
```

Комппилятор выдаёт:
[Warning] Project2.dpr(14): Variable 'test' might not have been initialized

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы забыли создать экземпляр класса.

заменить:

```
test.Add(43);
```

на:

```
test := TMyClass.Create;
test.Add(43);
```